# Struggling solving a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I come across a differential equation in a paper I am reading, although the result is given, I can't quite figure out how it is done.
The equation is 
$$b'(s)=(s-b(s))(n-1)(f(s)/F(s))$$
Where $f(s)$ and $F(s)$ are **p.d.f** and **c.d.f** of arbitrary distribution.
There is a boundary condition 
$$b(0)=0$$
I just don't know where to start, I tried dividing $b(s)$ and taking $log$ but it's not helping a lot.
Can someone give me a hint of how to crack a start?
Thanks

Comment: Can you use LaTeX please?

Comment: Isn't $n-1$ an exponent ?

Comment: No, (n-1) is a factor, I'll try type it in latex, I'm sending this on the phone app and it's not working so well... I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

First, it's useful to realise that the cumulative distribution function is the integral of the probability distribution function, i.e.
\begin{equation}
F(s) = \int_{-\infty}^s f(\sigma)\,\text{d}\sigma.
\end{equation}
Therefore, we can write $f(s) = F'(s)$ and therefore
\begin{equation}
(n-1) \frac{f(s)}{F(s)} = (n-1) \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} s} \log F(s) = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} s} \log F(s)^{n-1}.
\end{equation}
If we now write the differential equation as
\begin{equation}
\frac{\text{d} b}{\text{d} s} + b(s) \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} s} \log F(s)^{n-1} = s \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} s} \log F(s)^{n-1},
\end{equation}
we see that the homogeneous equation 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\text{d} b_h}{\text{d} s} + b_h(s) \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} s} \log F(s)^{n-1} = 0
\end{equation}
is solved by $b_h(s) = c\,F(s)^{1-n}$, where $c$ is an arbitrary constant. The method of [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) can now be used to find the solution to the full problem, which is given by
\begin{align}
b(s) &= F(s)^{1-n} \left[c + \int_{-\infty}^s (n-1) F(\sigma)^{n-2} F'(\sigma)\,\sigma \,\text{d}\sigma\right]\\
&= F(s)^{1-n} \left[c + \int_{-\infty}^s \sigma \left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} \sigma} F(\sigma)^{n-1}\right)\text{d}\sigma\right]\\
&= F(s)^{1-n} \left[c + s  F(s)^{n-1}- \int_{-\infty}^s F(\sigma)^{n-1}\text{d}\sigma\right]\\
&= s + F(s)^{1-n}\left[c - \int_{-\infty}^s F(\sigma)^{n-1}\text{d}\sigma\right]
\end{align}
using integration by parts. The boundary condition $b(0) = 0$ can now be used to determine the constant $c$, yielding
\begin{align}
b(s) &= s + F(s)^{1-n}\left[\int_{-\infty}^0 F(\sigma)^{n-1}\text{d}\sigma - \int_{-\infty}^s F(\sigma)^{n-1}\text{d}\sigma\right]\\
&= s - F(s)^{1-n} \int_0^s F(\sigma)^{n-1}\text{d}\sigma,
\end{align}
which might be closer to the result in the paper you're reading.